# The arguments of rm() in language R

Tags: r

I am new in language R,I found something special with it.
When using the method `rm()`,I wonder why I can't pass `ls()` as a parameter.
while using `rm(list = ls())` will pass the compilation.
The method `ls()` will return a data whose type is List,won't it ?
It is the first time that I ask a question at foreign website, and my English is terrible, sorry! Waiting for your answers!

Comment: Nope. The method `ls()` will return a data whose type is character. See `class(ls())`

Comment: That's just the way it goes.  What's wrong with using `rm(list = ls())`?

Comment: I just wonder why I can't use 'rm(ls())'

Comment: Have you studied `help("rm")`? Why doesn't that help page answer your question?

Comment: Sorry,I just went out and couldn't reply to you in time. 'Usage which(x, arr.ind = FALSE, useNames = TRUE) 'Ummm,just like this, we can use the method above passing a parameter "TRUE" or a parameter "arr.ind = TRUE", but for the method 'rm()',passing a parameter "ls()" rather than "rm(list = ls())" won't pass the complilation.And I have read the help page,but I can't understand it ......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has to do with the `...` special argument in R (AKA "dot-dot-dot" or "ellipsis"). `...` captures all unnamed arguments (as well as undocumented named arguments), "positionnally".

See `?rm` for its arguments: `rm(..., list = character(), pos = -1, envir = as.environment(pos), inherits = FALSE)`.
Since `...` is the first argument, it captures `ls()` in `rm(ls())`.
But there are expectations on `...` as you can see in the source code of `rm` (simply type `rm` at the command line):

```
function (..., list = character(), pos = -1, envir = as.environment(pos), 
  inherits = FALSE) 
{
  dots <- match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)$...
  if (length(dots) && !all(vapply(dots, function(x) is.symbol(x) || 
    is.character(x), NA, USE.NAMES = FALSE))) 
    stop("... must contain names or character strings")
  names <- vapply(dots, as.character, "")
  if (length(names) == 0L) 
    names <- character()
  list <- .Primitive("c")(list, names)
  .Internal(remove(list, envir, inherits))
}
```

Here it is `is.symbol()` that fails.

Maybe it will be easier with an example:

```
foo <- 1L
bar <- 2L
rm(ls())
# Error
ls()
# [1] "bar" "foo"
rm(c("foo", "bar"))
# Same error
rm("foo", "bar")
# OK
```

If you want to investigate further, I suggest: `debugonce(rm)` then `rm(ls())` then step by step execution (easier in an IDE like RStudio).